# xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcode-select", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods

when I execute the command “pod update”,I found some problems in this process.The detail information is as follows.

$ pod update

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.1.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies

**sh: line 1:  4173 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find xcode-select 2> /dev/null
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcode-select", not a developer tool or in PATH**

Downloading dependencies

Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)

Using MJExtension (3.0.12)

Using ReactiveCocoa (2.1.8)

Using SDWebImage (3.8.1)

Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.

$

I was struck by the problem very long .I hope for your help!Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19):

1. opened Xcode.
2. Preferences
3. Locations
4. Selected the Command Lin Tools

credit : http://www.jianshu.com/p/6b56aba2ee05